# Project Euler 1:Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000, works for 10 numbers but doesn't work for 1000

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, sum

> > > > If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

So I decided to try and solve some problems on Euler site to improve with programming. While trying to solve the first problem I wrote a quick code to count the sum and it worked for 10 numbers, but for 1000 it shows me the answer: 166833 which is wrong and I can't really find an issue here. If someone could give me a hint to improve my algorythm so it would work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Multiplies_of_3_and_5
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        int[] array = new int[7000];

        for (int j = 0; j<array.Length ;j++)
        {
            array[j] = j + 1;
        }

        int n = 1;
        int z = 1;
        int numbers = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<999; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == 3 * n )
            {
                n++;                    
                numbers += array[i];
            }

            else if (array[i] == 5 * z)
            {
                z++;
                numbers += array[i];
            }                                                           
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers));
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the modulo operator (%) instead?

Comment: Also, you don't need the loop to populate the array. You can do this with one loop, from 3-1000. Look into the [modulus operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Well, because array starts from 0. So if I want to get 1000 numbers I need to write 999. If I give program 1000 then it reads that as 1001. At least thats what I think from testing it on 10 numbers.

Comment: Your premise seems flawed. There aren't 1000 multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. Can you clarify?

Comment: I might try using %... It would be probably much easier and more logical, but is my version wrong in any way? From my perspective it should count it as well as %

Comment: Yes and under index 998 there is number 999. So it would mean that the last number checked is 999 so 1 below 1000. Am I wrong?

Comment: OK, your indexing is very confusing. You really don't need an array for this because you could simply calculate the value being checked inside the later loop instead of having 2 separate loops. Then you wouldn't need to store all those numbers. But I guess I don't see anything *wrong* about that part now that you've explained it.

Comment: Also: if n increases z won't increase (cases like 15, 30, ...)

Comment: Oh I just made my problem worse cause of those arrays and loops. Thanks for help @BlueMonkMN.

Comment: Also I think that is the problem I was looking for  and that is why I have less numbers then I should. Tho I will try using (%) instead as it seems easier. Thanks for help! @Cyphrags

Comment: You do not need the array at all. Just write i+1 instead of array[i].

Answer (score 4):

Idea count 3s, 5s and deduct 15s as they are in both but only need counting once.

```
int maxNum = 999;
int num3s = maxNum/3; // rounded down 333
int num5s = maxNum/5; // rounded down 199

int num15s = maxNum/15; // rounded down 66
```

Knowing how many still isn't going to tell us the sum. Pythagoras to the rescue.

```
sum3s = 3+6+9+12+15 (=45)
sum5s = 5+10+15     (=30) 
sum15s = 15         (=15)
```

average = (max+min)/2

Either there is an odd number of 3's, 5's or 15's and you get an even average. Or there is an even number in which case /2 and the even cancel each other.

So we get

```
sumXs = (min+max)*numXs
```

In the above case we get

```
sum3s = (3+15)/2*5 = 45
sum5s = (5+15)/2*3 = 30
sum15s = (15+15)/2*1 = 15


int sum = sum3s+sum5s-sum15s = 60;
```

Another example 11

```
sum = (3+9)/2*3 + (5+10)/2*2 - 0 = 33
```

And finally sum of 3s and 5s up to 999

```
sum = (3+999)/2*333 + (5+995)/2*199 - (15+990)/2*66
    = 501*333 + 500*199 - (1005)*66/2 
    = 501*333 + 500*199 - 1005*33 
    =  166833 +   99500 -   33165
    =  233168
```

Which is also the result of the programs.

Comment: This finds the number of multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000, while the problem posed was to find the sum of those multiples.

Comment: @Saedeas, thanks, I knew there was something wrong, see the updated answer.

Comment: This still isn't going to solve the stated problem? Knowing there are 200 values that divide by 5 doesn't mean those values sum to 5*200. 

Pretend we were only doing this until 11.  The answer would be 3+5+6+9+10 = 33.  Not 3*3+5*2=19 (which is what your code would calculate).

Comment: @Saedeas, OK so we can conclude I can't read :)

Comment: Looks better now and is a pretty quick solution to this problem! Nice.

Answer (score 3):

You should read up on the modulo operator (%).

```
  static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=1; i< 1000; i++){
      if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0){
        sum += i;
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
  }
```

To give an explanation, the modulo operator gives the remainder when performing integer division on a value.

For example, 6 % 3 == 0 (3 evenly divides 6), 7 % 3 == 1 (7 divided by 3 leaves remainder 1).

So to sum all of the multiples of 3 and 5, just check if the value divides evenly by 3 or 5 (the if statement), and if so, add it to the running sum.

Note that your algorithm is going to screw up when you get to numbers that are multiple of 3 AND 5.  You never add to z in that case. You also need to change it to be <= 999, not <999 (you will never add 999 in your code, which divides by 3).

To sum things up:

1. Use your loop variable directly, no need to pre-populate another
   array or have separate values keeping track of what multiple you're
   at.
2. Modulo is super useful.

Comment: Thats works perfectly.. Tho I am quite dissapointed with my code that didn't do the same. I already knows how (%) works but didn't use it here... who know why. Also I have one more question. How is this code bypassing the problem of counting as example 15 twice. I guess it is because we are having || statement here so when we get to 15,30 etc. it adds the sum only once? Am I right?

Comment: Your code fails at 15 because you don't update z at 15 (you hit your first if, increment n, but never increment z, which you have to do because 15 is a multiple of 5).

This code works because you're adding all the multiples of 3 or 5, which is the condition I coded in directly.

if (multiple of 3 or multiple of 5) add the number.

15 is a multiple of both, but it's still only added once.  The addition is separate from the conditional statement.

Comment: Ok. As I really wanted to fix my program and make it work, after your explanation I did it and it works just fine, but it is surely worse than Yours using (%). Will post my code in answer. Thanks a lot! I finally understand how it works.

Comment: Make sure you change the loop in your code to be <= 999 as well.  You need to add 999 for the correct result.

Comment: That's what I did and also posted it below. Works just fine right now. And I also added statement so program doesn't count numbers that are multiplied by 5 and 3 twice. Well, that is a simple thing, but I feel much better after solving it hah.

Comment: You didn't solve it.  Looks like Saedeas did.  Think about the way his code was written.  It's more than just the statements: it's about readability and conciseness.

Comment: Well... I can't disagree. But he showed me they way he did it and I was able to use it in my code. Also I learned about how useful is modulu which I will be able to use in the future for sure. I am just learning and I am proud even of small things I am able to achive.

Answer (score 1):

When reaching 15, n will increase but z won't. Therefore the second branch ("is divideable by 5") won't trigger anymore.

You can either use flags for both and then use those flags to increase numbers, n and z or use modulo as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 999).Sum(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 ? x : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

After listening to tips from You I remade my code and it works just fine. But it is surely a pain to do it this way, so I suggest using (%) for that. Anyway I will post my code here as well. Thanks for help again!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Multiplies_of_3_and_5
{
  class Program
  {


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] array = new int[7000];

        for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            array[j] = j + 1;
        }


        int n = 1;
        int z = 1;
        int numbers = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
        {

            if (array[i] == 3*n && array[i] == 5*z)
            {
                n++;
            }

            if (array[i] == 3 * n)
            {

                n++;
                numbers += array[i];
            }

            if (array[i] == 5 * z)
            {
                z++;
                numbers += array[i];
            }




        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```